# Render Mermaid diagram with Blazor WebAssembly App in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, blazor, markup, blazor-webassembly, mermaid

I have followed the guide for `Deploying Mermaid` here:

https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/?id=deploying-mermaid

Using it on codepen works directly:

https://codepen.io/Ogglas/pen/MWjWNxR

```
mermaid.initialize({
  startOnLoad:true
});

<div class="mermaid">
    graph LR
        A[Client] --- B[Load Balancer]
        B-->C[Server01]
        B-->D(Server02)
</div>
```

To enable it in Blazor i edited BlazorApp.Client -> wwwroot -> index.html and added the following below `<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>`.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script>mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});</script>
```

I then edited `Index.razor` with the following values:

```
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="mermaid">
    graph LR
        A[Client] --- B[Load Balancer]
        B-->C[Server01]
        B-->D(Server02)
</div>
```

However this does not render the mermaid diagram. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with a button click for now:

Index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <button @onclick="TriggerClick">
        Trigger Mermaid diagram render
    </button>
</div>

<div>
    Graph:
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {

    public async Task TriggerClick()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("renderMermaidDiagram");
    }
}
```

index.html, add this to the **`<head>`** section:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.renderMermaidDiagram = () => {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        var input = "graph LR \n" +
            "A[Client] --- B[Load Balancer] \n" +
            "B-->C[Server01] \n" +
            "B-->D(Server02) \n";
        mermaid.mermaidAPI.render('theGraph', input, function (svgCode) {
            output.innerHTML = svgCode;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Will look like this:

[image]

Note that some of the tutorials for mermaid uses outdated versions and will not work with the latest releases.

Sources:

https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/Tutorials?id=mermaid-with-html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

For serverside i have some rendering problems as well. (still investigating why so i can fix this)

***Current situation for serverside:***

Add this part of html in your page with reference to js file from mermaid.

```
<div class="mermaid">
   graph LR
   A[Client] --- B[Load Balancer]
   B-->C[Server01]
   B-->D(Server02)
</div>
```

This renders normal in pre-rendering part, but the second part when the app bootstraps it's plain text again.

You can test this by adding this in the "@code" section of the page

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   string t = "Set breakpoint on this line, this will be hit 2 times";
}
```

The strange part is if you add or not "the part to initialze mermaid" i get the same behavior result.

```
mermaid.initialize({
        startOnLoad: true
    });
```

***Clienside***

I found this clientside nuget solution that works smooth

→ https://github.com/TrueCommerce/MermaidJS.Blazor

Comment: Just as a PSA; MermaidJSBlazor (as of November 2022) is using an older version of Mermaid.  There have been some features added to newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Mermaid (8.11.5 used for testing) + Blazor server-side solution (this has not been tested with client-side):

I put JS inter-op in its own object and file, e.g. `blazor-helper.js`:

```js
var JsFunctions = window.JsFunctions || {};
JsFunctions = {
    MermaidInitialize: function() {
        mermaid.initialize({
            startOnLoad: true,
            securityLevel: "loose",
            // Other options.
          });
    },

    MermaidRender: function() {
        mermaid.init();
    }
};
```

Obviously, one could get away without abstracting `mermaid.init()`, but I think it provides clarity.

Then in your blazor code (c#9 syntax with nullable enabled):

```cs
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime? JsRuntime { get; set; } = null;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(this.JsRuntime is not null)
        {
            if(firstRender)
            {
                await this.JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JsFunctions.MermaidInitialize");
            }

            await this.JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JsFunctions.MermaidRender");
        }
    }
```